# Sql server conversion to in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that works.  One field is in the query is:

```
HASHBYTES('MD5', table1.field1 + table1.field2 + table1.field3) as OUT_NAME
```

this gave a wierd looking string.  I want to have this be a 32 bit hex string so I tried surrounding the hashbyte calculation with (from a suggesting in the sqlserver newsgroup)

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), THE-HASHBYTE-STUFF, 2) AS OUT_NAME.
```

I also tried (this worked elsewhere in the query)

```
SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(THE-HASHBYTE-STUFF), 3, 32) AS OUT_NAME
```

Both of those gave errors in converting a varchar to an int.

I also tried converting each piece int he HASHBYTES to a varchar or to an nvarchar and still got errors in the pieces -- even though the one without any conversions -- the plain HASHBYTES -- worked.  I also tried CAST, but still had those errors.

Why does

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), something-that-works, 2)
```

fail -- and with a conversion to int?

Comment: Can you show the contents of the columns and give us some clue what you expected as output (like show us the actual string instead of just describing it vaguely)?

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 0xBEEF, 2)` - prior to SQL 2008 will output the result of the conversion of the binary bytes to ASCII characters (Not what you want, your *weird string*). For 2008 onwards it will output the string `'BEEF'`.  `fn_varbintohexstr` should work on any version, if it does not you need to add a reproducible example.